# Remove elements from an array which have a substring that is itself an element of the array

Tags: arrays, perl

In Perl, I'd like to remove all elements from an array where another element of the same array is a non-empty substring of said element.

Say I have the array

```
@itemlist = ("abcde", "ab", "khi", "jklm");
```

In this instance I would like to have the element `"abcde"` removed, because `"ab"` is a substring of `"abcde"`.

I could make a copy of the array (maybe as a hash?), iterate over it, try to index with every element of the original array and remove it, but there has to be a more elegant way, no?

Thanks for your help!

*Edited for clarity a bit.*

Comment: this has HOMEWORK written all over it ...

Comment: It's not homework. The items in question are supposed to work as synonyms for other items in a search query, and since the search algorithm apparently does a full substring search anyway, I was asked to remove every synonym that consists of a shorter co-synonym.

Comment: What size of @itemlist do you expect to handle?

Comment: I'd expect not to have more than, say, 12-15 items in there.

Comment: Would you consider `oba` to be a substring of `foobar`? In other words, is the "synonyms" only the beginnings of the words, like abbreviations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could construct a regex from all the items and throw out anything that matches:

```
$alternation = join('|', map(quotemeta, @itemlist));
@itemlist = grep !/($alternation).|.($alternation)/, @itemlist;
```

The `().|.()` thing just ensures that an item doesn't match itself.

Comment: This seems to have worked. Had to lc the whole thing first, but that was my mistake, I didn't specify that. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I wouldn't call this elegant, but here goes:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @itemlist = ("abcde", "ab", "khi", "jklm");

@itemlist = grep { 
    @itemlist ~~ sub {$_ !~ /(?:.\Q$_[0]\E|\Q$_[0]\E.)/} 
} @itemlist;

print "@itemlist";
```

It relies on a rather obscure behavior of [smart match](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator): if the left argument is an array and the right argument a sub, it calls the sub for each element, and the final result is true only if the sub returns true for each element.

Explanation: for each element of the array, it checks that no other element is a substring of that element (requiring at least one additional character so that elements won't match themselves).

**Note:** wdebeaum's answer is probably the one I would prefer in the real world.  Still, it is kind of interesting the strange things one can do with smart match.

Comment: Thank you, too. Learned that I need to read more about the smart match operator, if nothing else it looks cool in code. :)

Answer (score 0):

wdebeaum's answer is the solution to use, not the one below, but I learned something by doing it and perhaps someone else will too.  After I had written mine I decided to test it on lists of several thousand elements.

b.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @itemlist = <>;
for(@itemlist) { chomp; }
my $regex;

if(defined $ENV{wdebeaum}) {
    # wdebeaum's solution
    my $alternation = join('|', map(quotemeta, @itemlist));
    $regex = qr/(?:$alternation).|.(?:$alternation)/;
} else {
    # my solution
    $regex = join "|", map {qq{(?:\Q$_\E.)|(?:.\Q$_\E)}} @itemlist;
}

my @result = grep !/$regex/, @itemlist;
print scalar @itemlist, "\t", scalar @result, "\n";
```

I generated a list of 5000 random words.

```
sort -R /usr/share/dict/american-english|head -5000 > some-words
```

For small lists both solutions seem fine.

```
$ time head -200 some-words | wdebeaum=1 ./b.pl
200 198

real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.004s

$ time head -200 some-words | ./b.pl
200 198

real    0m0.068s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.004s
```

But for larger lists, wdebeaum's is clearly better.

```
$ time cat some-words | wdebeaum=1 ./b.pl 
5000    1947

real    0m0.068s
user    0m0.064s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time cat some-words | ./b.pl 
5000    1947

real    0m8.305s
user    0m8.277s
sys     0m0.012s
```

I think the reason for the difference, is that even though both regular expressions have the same number of possible paths, my regex has more paths that have to be tried, since it has the same number of `.`s as paths, while wdebebaum's has only two.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash to count substrings of all the words. Any word in the list that has a higher count than one is then a substring of another word. The minimum length of the substrings is two in this example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @list = qw(abcde ab foo foobar de oba cd xs);

my %count;

for my $word (@list) {
    my $len = length $word;
    $count{$word}++;
    for my $start (0 .. $len - 2) {
        for my $long (2 .. $len - 2) {
            my $sub = substr($word, $start, $long);
            $count{$sub}++;
        }
    }
}
say for grep $count{$_} == 1, @list;
```

**Output:**

```
abcde
foobar
xs
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will remove the substring from the array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @ar=("asl","pwe","jsl","nxu","sl","baks","ak");
foreach my $i (@ar){
  my $p = grep /$i/, @ar;
  if ( $p == 1 ){
    print "$i" , "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the inverse problem: removing from the list strings which are substrings of other strings. Here is my not-too-elegant solution.

```
sub remove_substrings_from_list {
    my @list = @_;
    my @vals_without_superstrings;

    my %hash_of_others;
    for ( 0 .. $#list ) {
        my $a = shift @list;
        $hash_of_others{$a} = [ @list ];
        push @list, $a;
    }
    foreach my $k ( keys %hash_of_others ) {
        push @vals_without_superstrings, $k unless grep { index( $_, $k ) != -1 } @{ $hash_of_others{$k} };
    }
    return @vals_without_superstrings;
}
```